# Error while reading csv file

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a xlsx file and to read from Rstudio i saved it as .csv file. Now when i try to read the file from Rstudio, receiving the below error.

```
setwd("D:/DATA SCIENCE/CCPP-Linear regression")
ccpp<- read.csv("Folds5x2_pp.csv", header = TRUE)
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
>   'Folds5x2_pp.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: You have set the working directory so the csv file was probably saved somewhere else. You can click on "Files" tab in RStudio and check if it is there. Another reason might that your file was not saved with the right extension so R can not find the name you are giving it.

Comment: In Excel, check the directory to which the file was saved: it is not safe to assume it is in the same directory as the original xlsx file. To see what R is looking at, try `list.files()` to see if your file is there slightly mis-spelled or with a different extension. Alternatively, you can use [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) or [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html)

Comment: Thanks guys.. Its working for me now. I missed to set the path properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the "cannot open the connection" part of the error message confirms that where R is looking is not where the file is.

A few things to keep in mind

- use `getwd()` to see the current R working directory
- use `setwd()` to change R's wd
- You should use RStudio projects to organize your projects - this helps with the working directory thing
- spaces in paths are difficult sometimes. Looks like you have "D:/DATA SCIENCE", that space can cause problems (you may need to escape the space like `"DATA\ SCIENCE"`.
- You can read the file using the full path (e.g. `read.csv("D:/DATA SCIENCE/path/file.csv")`) or if you are doing this a lot, set a variable to your path `data_path ="D:/DATA SCIENCE/path/"` and then `read.csv(file.path(data_path, "file.csv"))` where `file.path` concatenates with your OS specific path delimiter.
- You can import files into RStudio using the Import Dataset option under Tools in the menu bar.

Comment: Thanks guys.. Its working for me now. I missed to set the path properly.

Comment: You should upvote the comments that were helpful and/or accept an answer to help other users find this question.