# R cannot open a connection

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to use RTextTools for none .csv files.

```
data7 <- read_data('/Users/Ziegler1812/Desktop/Essays/Fall 2016/461/Data-PrelimforR/Data-PrelimforR4/', type = 'folder',index = '1.txt',1)
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '1.txt': No
>   such file or directory

'1.txt' does in fact exist in that location, the problem is not the file's existence, it is getting to the location of the file.

Comment: If the trouble is getting to the location of the file, you can help it by writing `file.path(path_to_file, "1.txt")` instead..?

Comment: Some general hints about this kind of error from a [previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708725/error-while-reading-csv-file/39709571).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in RTextTools the index is not to be an index from within the folder, it is to either be the folder itself, or an outside entity that is similar to that within the folder. Further, the explanation shows that folder is for txt files, however 'delim' is for txt files, which is why I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks.