# File doesn't exist when using read_csv

Tags: r

I definitely have "data.csv" file in my working directory.
but file doesn't exist error keep taking place and making me tired.
you can see below code and result from R script.
I would really appreciate your help.

```
> file.exists("./input/data.csv")
[1] TRUE
> farmData <- read_csv("./input/data.csv")
Error: 'C:/Users/live_/OneDrive/?? ??/tidyverse practice/input/data.csv' does not exist.
```

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708725/error-while-reading-csv-file. Do you have a space in your full path? The "?? ??" part looks odd. Does it work with `read.csv` rather than `read_csv`? Can you use `read_csv(file.choose())` and manually select the file?

Answer (score 1):

really thank you guys for helping me.
the problem was "?? ??" was the "Desktop" in Korean.
I made a mistake with R studio by using foreign language.
I changed the set up of my Window and redirect this file and finally solved this issue.

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/live_/Desktop/tidyverse practice"
> file.exists("./input/data.csv")
[1] TRUE
> farmData <- read.csv("./input/data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good coding practice, never have space in your directories. Replace them with underscore. Another suggestion is to replace / with **//** or **\**

If it still doesn't work; try Ctrl+Shift+H to set the working directory same as the folder that as your .csv file.